# What are commands that you can send to vncaddrbook?

Tags: realvnc, vnc-viewer

I was looking at REALVNC today and I noticed there's a program called `vncaddrbook.exe`, I looked at the `-help` and noticed that you can specify `[COMMAND]` but I can't find what commands can be specified or what it is exactly that any of those commands would do.

What commands are available, and where could I find them?  I even looked in their documentation and there's nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

The only command for vncaddressbook.exe is the "-h all" command to show advanced usage information

[image: advanced usage]